# How to replace sub query with join in mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I have following query.

```
select paytype, sum(amtpaid)
from `tbl_payments`
where locationid = 3  and
      checkstatus not in ('Refund','Tip','Tipadj') and
      paytype not in ('Void', 'Comp') and
      oid in (select oid
              from `tbl_checkout_stage`
              where locationid = 3
              group by oid
              having count(checkid) = sum(checkstatus = 'Paid')
             )
group by paytype
```

How can I replace the sub query with join in above case.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: x join subquery y on y.oid = y.oid

Answer (score 0):

Try this query

```
select paytype, sum(amtpaid)
from `tbl_payments`
join (select oid
              from `tbl_checkout_stage`
              where locationid = 3
              group by oid
              having count(checkid) = sum(checkstatus = 'Paid')
             ) a on a.oid=`tbl_payments`.oid
where locationid = 3  and
      checkstatus not in ('Refund','Tip','Tipadj') and
      paytype not in ('Void', 'Comp') and
group by paytype
```